# Smallest Sigma Field

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I have a doubt in the problem below regarding its solution:

Find the smallest $\sigma$ - field on $\Omega$ = $\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$ such that the function $X(\omega)$ = $1 + \omega$ is random variable.

The solution I have found out is $\{\Omega, \phi, \{-2,-1,0,1\},\{2\}\}$
Is it correct or i have to add something more?
Please help...

Comment: Your solution cannot be a sigma-field, since you have a mixture of sets and numbers in there. A sigma-field must be a subset of the power set of $\Omega$.

Comment: sorry it was a typo... corrected now...

Comment: Perhaps a better place to start with is this: can you define what it means for $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ to be considered a random variable?

Comment: @JonathanY. It means that X is a function whose domain is $\Omega$ and whose range is a set of real numbers.

Comment: If that were the case, then the $\sigma$-field $\Omega$ is endowed with would make no difference; where does it factor in, then?

Comment: @JonathanY. that is where I am confused as to how to relate Random Variables with $\sigma$ - field.

Comment: Okay then. As the ['fine print' here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Definition) notes, we typically say that $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is an RV whenever the preimage of any Borel set on $\mathbb{R}$ is measurable in $\Omega$, i.e., an event. Put differently, an RV is a [measurable function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_function) from $\Omega$ with its prescribed $\sigma$-algebra to $\mathbb{R}$ with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.